# How to implement this filtering on List

Tags: scala

I have the following list of objects:-

```
case class Account(id: Long, locked: Boolean)

val a1 = Account(1, false)
val a2 = Account(2, false)
val a3 = Account(3, true)
val a4 = Account(4, true)

val accounts = List(a1, a2, a3, a4)
```

And here is a method which is working correctly.

```
def getAccounts(includeLocked: Boolean): List[Account] = {
  if(includeLocked) {
    accounts.filter(acc => acc.locked == false)
  } else {
    accounts
  }
}
```

Invoking `getAccounts(false)` correctly filters out locked Accounts and `getAccounts(false)` returns everything which is what I want.

```
getAccounts(false)
List(Account(1,false), Account(2,false))

getAccounts(true)
List(Account(1,false), Account(2,false), Account(3,true), Account(4,true))
```

But is there a more idiomatic way of implementing `getAccounts`?
My current `if(includeLocked)` approach feels rather clunky.

Comment: is your method `getAccounts` wrong that it should have `if(!includeLocked) {` because your example below for `getAccounts(false)` is not 
`List(Account(1,false), Account(2,false))` but is ` List(Account(1,false), Account(2,false), Account(3,true), Account(4,true))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented by others, it looks like `if(includeLocked)` should be `if(!includeLocked)` in your sample code.

A more concise version could be like the following:

```
def getAccounts(includeLocked: Boolean): List[Account] =
  accounts.filter(acc => includeLocked || !acc.locked)

getAccounts(true)
// res1: List[Account] = List(Account(1,false), Account(2,false), Account(3,true), Account(4,true))

getAccounts(false)
// res2: List[Account] = List(Account(1,false), Account(2,false))
```

Note that `if/else` (or pattern match) might be more verbose, it's probably more intuitive to read though.

Comment: Do note that this rewrite has performance implications. Previously, if you also wanted to include locked accounts, you simply returned the complete list. Now, every element in the list is checked and then returned. Personally, I'd prefer a separation where you simply write two functions: `getActiveAccounts` and `getAllAccounts` or some such.